# How to split the rent if two roommates live there from the beginning and a third one joins in the middle of the month?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, finance

I've been thinking over it and I can't figure it out.

> Consider the rent of the house is $X$. Now there are two roommates from the beginning and a third one joins in the middle of the month. Now how is the rent split?

**Solution 1:**

half month = $X/2$

1 share in first half $= X/2/2=X/4$

1 share in second half $= X/2/3=X/6$

Total from each person $= (X/4+X/6) + (X/4+X/6) + X/6$ which is
                   $5X/12 +5X/12 + X/6$

**Solution 2:**

Person A and Person B stayed = 30 days.

Person C stayed = 15 days.

Total days $= 30+ 30 + 15 = 75$

Therefore,  each share would be   $= 2X/5 + 2X/5 + X/5$

Both solutions seems to be correct, yet yields different shares. Can someone tell me the difference between the two and which old would be correct ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution assumes that the paid rent should be proportional to both the time spent and the area consumed. The second solution assumes that only the time should be considered. I suppose the first one is *more* realistic as the utility one person draws from the house can be assumed to be bigger if more personal space is available (whether this is the case to full extent - for example there is less social interaction possible in an empty house - is a different question). For some aspects the second method seems to be more appropriate, for exacmple if the rent is not fixed per month (for the house as a whole) but there are consumption dependent parts in it (e.g. water and electricity - three people may be assumed to consume more, for simplicity assumed in a proportional way, but that is also not absolutely true).
If we assum ethat the contract with the landlord fixed a rent that is the same every month independent of the number of inhabitants, then only method one is valid - just imagine the landlord would drop by every day to cash in $X/30$.

Comment: Thanks. As per your explanation, I see the second one as more realistic, since we all use the entire apartment. Meaning we don't consume area per person. So I thin calculating with proportianal to time gives a feel of equality among the 3.

Answer (score 1):

In your first method, you are splitting the rent such that there is the same cost per day, regardless of how many people are in the apartment each day.

In the second method, you are splitting the rent such that there is the same cost per day per person.

Neither is really more 'correct' than the other, as they are measuring different things.

Comment: The perception might well be that the first method is "fairer", since the third person is only paying a one-third share of the use of the house for half a month, while the second method treats time spent in the house for any resident as the same regardless of how many other people are living there during any interval.

Comment: I was thinking that the second one seemed 'fairer' to me, since the space gets more overall use during the second half than the first half -- more water used, etc, and so the total cost to the landlord for the second half would be greater than the cost for the first half. Also, realistically, I'd think that each person would just pay 1/3 the bill if the minimum lease period is a month, given that each person would have to pay the full bill for their stay were they not splitting.

Comment: yes.. i feel the second one 'fairer' too, after reading the answers.